# Typescript Interface properties are not showing in autosuggestion list

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code.

I have an interface 'Vehicle' with 4 optional properties and implemented in class 'Ford'.

I can't see the properties of an interface when I click  in class.Then I am getting and error while setting value for properties which is in interface.

Please refer screen shot below.

[image: Issue Image]

Answer (score 3):

You get an error because you don't declare field `name` in your class. As soon as you declare the field with correct name in your class the error message will go away:

```
interface Vehicle{
    name?: string;
    // rest of the code
}

class Ford implements Vehicle{
    name:string;  // <- as soon as you add the field the error message will go away
    constructor(){
        this.name="vimal";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I implement a field? `name:string` in `Ford` class is a declaration. 
`this.name="vimal"` is implementation or assignment

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VimalRaj You still need to declare the field in class declaration. Having only `this.name = "value"` in constructor does not declare field automatically